# Splitting a single package/module into multiple (many) files gives undefined error on go build ./

Tags: go

I like splitting my modules/packages into many files (e.g. a bigger function file and a coupled helpers file). Now a module can have many bigger functions as it grows. Let's say my modules/packages each consist of around 30 files.

When I started working with Go a few days ago, I was a bit confused about the module pattern. I have a JavaScript (ES6+) background. After some research, I found you could build packages consisting of multiple files by running the following command `go build ./...`. This worked out pretty well, until my package consisted of about 10 files. All of a sudden I saw errors about functions being undefined. Meanwhile those functions where clearly defined in the src of the module/package (and properly capitalized).

My gut feeling says that this is because of the build order. Say we have 2 files 'a.go' and 'b.go'. file 'a.go' got a reference to a function in file 'b.go'. When file 'a.go' is build before 'b.go', an undefined error appears. My second gut feeling is that file 'a.go' contains a reference to a function inside file 'b.go' and the same vice-versa. So file 'b.go' also has reference to a function in file 'a.go'.

1. Is my first of my second gut feeling correct?
2. How do people commonly tackle this problem, or even better, what is the best practice?
3. What is the proper way creating a single module which consists out of many files?

Comment: You don't build multiple files with `./...`, the `...` is a wildcard to reference multiple _packages_.  The `go` commands reference packages, and packages can have as many files as you want. See [How to Write Go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code.html) for the basics (and https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules if you're starting with modules)

Comment: All files in the package have the same package name. Is this what you mean with having as many files as you want?

Comment: I mean that you can have as many files in a package as you want (within system limits). Yes, all files in the same package have the same package name of course, and a single package is contained in a directory. The compiler has no notion of individual source files, and compiles the aggregate source for each package. You will have to create a [mre] in order for someone to help diagnose whatever problem you're facing.

Comment: I think I'm facing a circular dependency issue. Go does not accept this, am I right?

Comment: Go does not allow circular imports of _packages_. This has always been the case, or at least since before Go 1.0.  I would echo the suggestion to read ["How to Write Go Code"](https://golang.org/doc/code.html), which covers a lot of what you are asking about in terms of the older GOPATH-based system.

Comment: Also, question: have you opted-in to the new Go modules system? You are saying "modules/packages", but I suspect you might not actually mean the new Go modules system? (It is new as of Go 1.11, and opt-in only, so if you are new to Go and haven't consciously tried to enable the new Go modules system, there is a healthy chance you are not using modules, and instead are using the older GOPATH-based system).

Comment: Also, what is the exact error message you are seeing?

Answer (score 1):

You can have as many `.go` files in a single directory as you'd like.

A Go package consists of all of the `.go` files in a single directory. Each `.go` file in a single directory should have the same `package foo` declaration as the other `.go` files in the same directory.

Your source code imports code from another package (another directory) via an *import path* supplied in an import statement such as `import "github.com/my/repo/pkg1"`.

To build a package, you can `cd` to the directory and issue `go build .` (where `.` means build all the files in the current directory, or you can also just issue `go build` in that directory without any arguments because the default is `.`).

Code within the same package (the same directory) can reference code in other files in the same package (same directory) without needing to import the other files, and without needing the symbols to be exported (uppercase first character).

It is well worth the time to read ["How to Write Go Code"](https://golang.org/doc/code.html), which includes an overview of these concepts, including:

> Go programmers typically keep all their Go code in a single *workspace*.
>
> - A workspace contains many version control repositories (managed by Git, for example).
> - Each repository contains one or more *packages*.
> - Each package consists of one or more Go source files in a single directory.
> - The path to a package's directory determines its *import path*.

and a bit later it describes the relationship between "workspace" and GOPATH:

> The GOPATH environment variable specifies the location of your workspace. It defaults to a directory named go inside your home directory, so $HOME/go on Unix, $home/go on Plan 9, and %USERPROFILE%\go (usually C:\Users\YourName\go) on Windows.

Regarding your more specific concerns:

*Splitting a single package into multiple (many) files gives undefined error on go build ./*

Splitting a package across multiple individual `.go` files in the same directory (same package) should not cause a problem in and of itself, but of course it needs to be done properly (e.g., all `.go` files in the same directory (same package) need to have the same `package foo` declaration near the top; files in the same directory should not attempt to use `import` statements to import other files in the same directory; etc.).

*My gut feeling says that this is because of the build order.*

Build order shouldn't matter here.

*My second gut feeling is that file 'a.go' contains a reference to a function inside file 'b.go' and the same vice-versa. So file 'b.go' also has reference to a function in file 'a.go'.*

This is fine if `a.go` and `b.go` are in the same package (the same directory).

On the other hand, this is not allowed if `a.go` and `b.go` are in the different packages (different directories). This is because Go does not allow circular dependencies at the package level.  If this is the problem, the simplest solution is to move `a.go` and `b.go` into the same directory, or refactor to introduce a third package to break the cycle so that `a` and `b` can both depend on the third package, or use interfaces, or other possible solutions, but given you say you are new to Go, the simplest solution might be best while you are learning.